# scrollView fetching process

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have rotated my collectionView upside down so it would load the content at the top instead of at the bottom and I added this:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

    if maxOffset - currentOffset <= 10{
        fetch()
    }
}
```

but nothing gets fetch even though on the console it's printing every time I go reach the bottom. `fetch()` works, calling it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing using this and it works fine.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height + 50 /* 50 its just example for your like */ {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                fetch()
            }
    }
}
```